# Displaying records from database by quarter in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table named nca_totals.

```
Table: nca_totals
+----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| total_id | nca_total | nca_date   | account_type |
+----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
|       13 | 10450     | 2015-01-21 | DBP-TRUST    |
|       14 | 5000      | 2015-02-05 | DBP-TRUST    |
|       15 | 7000      | 2015-04-02 | DBP-TRUST    |
|       16 | 4000      | 2015-05-02 | DBP-TRUST    |
+----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

Now I want to display all the data by quarter base on its date. Let's say I want to display all the records who belong to **1st Quarter** like this:

```
+----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| total_id | nca_total | nca_date   | account_type |
+----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
|       13 | 10450     | 2015-01-21 | DBP-TRUST    |
|       14 | 5000      | 2015-02-05 | DBP-TRUST    |
+----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

This date belongs to the 1st quarter of the year (Jan, Feb, March). I only have this query to select the date and return its quarter number as:

```
SELECT QUARTER('2015-01-11');       /* returns 1 */
```

How can I combine that query to display all the records by quarter ? Can anyone help ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from nca_totals 
where QUARTER(nca_date) = 1
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT
    CEIL(MONTH(`nca_date`) / 3) AS `quarter`
FROM `nca_totals`;
```